# How to create inbound rule on EC2 instance for requests from hosted s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have my web app, written in vue, and deployed on S3 using static website hosting.

I also have an EC2 instance setup which will serve as the backend for my app.

My question is, I'd like to restrict access to the EC2 instance to only requests coming from the site hosted on S3. Is that possible?

I see in the security group for the EC2 instance, I can specify the inbound traffic rule to limit from a specific IP address. However I'm not sure how I can limit it to traffic from a particular *domain*

Comment: Simple answer: No. The static pages run on the user's browser, so it is not possible to isolate from where the requests will come.

Answer (score 0):

The S3 app speaking to your backend will actually be using the end users internet connection in order to communicate, so you cannot use a security group to prevent this access if your application should be available publicly.

You can however lock it down so that the application can only be called from valid domain(s) only.

To do this would need to be able to control traffic by the `referer` header, which would require you to configure an [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) and add a rule set to allow where the referer header is your domain. Then for default logic it would need to block it.

To use a WAF it would need to attached to one of the following resources:

- [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html)
- [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)
- [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)

The resource would sit in front of the EC2 host.

For more information take a look at the [How to Prevent Hotlinking by Using AWS WAF, Amazon CloudFront, and Referer Checking](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-by-using-aws-waf-amazon-cloudfront-and-referer-checking/) blog post.

Comment: Please note that the `referer` can be easily spoofed, so it is not a 'foolproof' technique for securing an application.

Comment: Very true @JohnRotenstein.